# Does Bot Framework Direct line support CORS?

Tags: angularjs, cors, botframework, botconnector, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to use Bot Framework's Direct Line API along with Angular.js. However, the request sent from Angular throws the Cross Origin error in my browser.

I need to know if I'm doing something wrong. If thats the case, I'll post the code.

So, Does Bot Framework Direct line support Cross Origin requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after adding `withCredentials:false` to my request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding cors support to your node api?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: The OP hasn't said they are using this with Node

Comment: oh sorry, are you writing your bot in c# or node? I just assumed he is working in node scince all of his stack overflow stuff is related to js and node. My guess is that the rest api is blocking the request and not the direct line api